# Is it possible to get and save the user device detail in the database while the user sign up with Firebase email auth?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a Firebase Sign Up activity with come custom fields other than email and password, that I store with their respected user ID. But I'm wondering if there is any way to also collect the user device details such as Device Model, Manufacturer, OS etc of the device that the user is using to sign up and save those details (only the first time when signing up) in the database with their respected user ID? So that I can get to the information of a user later on that what device that user has used to sign up.

Something like the following?

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText editTextName, editTextEmail, editTextPassword, editTextAddress, editTextDeviceModel, editTextOS;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        editTextName = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_name);
        editTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_email);
        editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_password);
        editTextAddress = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_address);

        //Here are the hidden fields that might hold the device info
        editTextDeviceModel = findViewById(R.id.device_model);
        editTextOS = findViewById(R.id.device_os);
        editTextDeviceModel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        editTextOS.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        final String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < AuthResult > () {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < AuthResult > task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        User user = new User(
                            name,
                            email,
                            address,
                            deviceModel,
                            os
                        );

                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                            .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < Void > () {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < Void > task) {
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Not successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

    }

}
```

This is the `User` class

```
public class User {
    public String name, email, address, deviceModel, os;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String email, String address, String deviceModel, String os) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
        //this.deviceModel = ???????;
        //this.os = ????;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is happening when you are using this code?

Comment: @AlexMamo, it saves the name, email, addresses successfully. But as you can see the I'm not sure how could I get the `deviceModel` and `os` in the `User` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, you need to change the following lines of code:

```
//this.deviceModel = ???????;
//this.os = ????;
```

to

```
this.deviceModel = deviceModel;
this.os = os;
```

To get the device model and the operation system, please use the following lines of code:

```
String deviceModel = Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL;
String os = "Android";
```

Since your app runs on an Android device, the `os` will always be Android. And when you create an object of `User` class, please the following lines of code:

```
User user = new User(name, email, address, deviceModel, os);
```

In the end, in your database, the user object will contain also the device model and the os.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for the lesson.

Comment: Hey, I just got a problem. When I tested it with the emulator, I got all the Build (I also tried HARDWARE, FINGERPRINT, and others) data. But when I tested it with a real device, I got no Build data at all. My emulator is on Android O, and tested in mobile running Android Marshmello. What could be the issue here?

Comment: This sounds as a new problem which is basically another question that I cannot responde in a comment or using the only the data above. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you.

Comment: Oh! I just have got the problem solved by making the variables global but wonder why it was not working in the actual device while working the same codebase in the emulator. Thanks anyway. Cheers.